# Como hacer un Select multiple compatible con Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, css, html5, multiselect

vi este select multiple en internet, https://www.cssscript.com/custom-dropdown-bvselect/ lo repliqué y funciona en mi navegador de Internet Explorer. El problema que al ponerlo en la computadora de mi trabajo, no lo carga igual.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo carga sin estilo ni nada, yo creo que es por algo de compatibilidad. o la version del navegador. Lo muestra así
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La version que tengo es esta creo que es verison 10
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi trabajo tienen la version 1909 creo que es version 9
como hago un select multiple que sea compatible con cualquier version de internet explorer?

codigo del html

```
<tr id=prov>
        <td align="right"></td>
        <td>
            <select id="cmbProv" name="cmbProv" class="prov-ext" multiple="" size="3" >
                <% 
                                dim prov_ext1
                                Set prov_ext1=oAccDatos.ObtenerProveedores()
                                If not prov_ext1.Eof Then
                                  Do While Not prov_ext1.Eof                        
                             %>
          <option value="<%= prov_ext1("PROVEEDOR_NOMBRE")%>"><%= prov_ext1("PROVEEDOR_NOMBRE")%></option>
          <%prov_ext1.movenext
                                  Loop
                                End If
                                   prov_ext1.close
                                   set prov_ext1 = Nothing
                             %>
            </select>
        </td>
      </tr>

<script src="./vanillaSelectBox.js"></script>
<script>

let selectProv = new vanillaSelectBox("#cmbProv",{placeHolder: "Indique Proveedor(es)","maxOptionWidth":400,"maxHeight": 300,"search": true,"stayOpen":false,translations: { "all": "Todos", "items": "Proveedores" } });


</script>
```

Ese es todo el código, solo implementé lo de la página y le puse lo que corresponde.

Comment: Hola, va a ser difícil que la comunidad te pueda apoyar si no provees un [mcve], recomiendo leas [ask]

Comment: A lo que se refería BetaM era que nos dejases aquí tu código (todo). Es posible que al pasar de un ordenador al otro te dejases algo o no cargue por un tema de rutas o cualquier otro motivo. Si nos pones el link solo podremos comprobar que funciona correctamente

Comment: Si, es que solo le implementé lo de la pagina, y le puse lo que le corresponde para que funcione.. pero ahí puse lo que yo añadí, ojalá pueda servir

Comment: en la documentación del código aconseja un [polyfill](https://github.com/BMSVieira/BVSelect-VanillaJS#polyfill) para navegadores obsoletos

Comment: como hago eso?, o sabrán como hacer un select multiple dropdown compatible con navegadores obsoletos? por favor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
```

Este código soluciona el problema de compatibilidad, cambia el modo de documento predeterminado al que hace compatible el sistema.